# exclude subview from UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
    UIView *superview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0, 0, 320, 480);
    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0, 0, 320, 480);
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handlePinch);
    superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    subview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [superview addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

I have a subview overlapping on top of a  superview. The subview has 4 buttons that needs to be tappable. The superview has a pinch-zoom gesture that zooms the view. But i would like to disable the zoom on the subview.
The recognizer is fired inside the subview as well, is there a way to exclude the recognizer from the subview?

Comment: You cant, because if you exclude gesture recognizer or user interaction on the subview this will effect superview since your frame size of both view are the same and subview completely overlap over your superview

Answer (score 0):

I used the simple way below:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view != subview) { // accept only touchs on superview, not accept touchs on subviews
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     UIView *superview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0, 0, 320, 480);
superview.tag=1; //set Tag for superview

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0, 0, 320, 480);
subview.tag==2; //set Tag for subview
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handlePinch);
    superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    subview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [superview addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{

    if(touch.view .tag==2) //if subview is touched then disable pinch gesture.
    {
        return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best option, but this could also work? Other StackOverflow users please be kind, I'm new!

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView: superview];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, touchPoint)
    {
         return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Apple Docs containing CGRectContainsPoint.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint